# InvalidCastException in Entity Framework 7

Tags: entity-framework

I'm using Visual Studio 2015, .Net framework 4.6.00079 to build a simple ASP.NET MVC 6 app:
model:

```
namespace RimconPensionModel.DataAccessLayer
{
    [Table("BaseMortality")]
        public class BaseMortality
    {
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string BaseMortalitySet { get; set; }
        public int Age { get; set; }
        public string Gender { get; set; }
        public float MortalityFactor { get; set; }
        public DateTime EffectiveDate { get; set; }
        public DateTime UpdateDate { get; set; }
        public string UpdateUser { get; set; }

   }
}
```

controller:

```
namespace RimconPensionModel.Controllers
{
    public class BaseMortalityController : Controller
    {
        [FromServices]
        public RimconPensionModelContext RimconPensionModelContext { get; set; }

        [FromServices]
        public ILogger<BaseMortalityController> Logger { get; set; }

        public IActionResult Index()
        {
            return View(RimconPensionModelContext.BaseMortality.ToList());
        }
   }
}
```

view:

```
@model  IEnumerable<RimconPensionModel.DataAccessLayer.BaseMortality>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Base Mortality Data";
}

<h2>Base Mortality Data</h2>
<!--
<p>
    <a asp-controller="BaseMortalityData" asp-action="Create">Create New</a>
</p> -->

<table class="table">
    <tr>
        <th>Base Mortality Sets</th>
    </tr>

    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.BaseMortalitySet)
            </td>
        </tr>
    }
</table>
```

The app builds and starts, but when I invoke the controller, I get InvalidCastException on the "return View( . . . )"  line of the controller. I've been googling for days (I'm a bit new to MVC and Entity Framework) with no luck.  I think it probably has something to do with the datetime attributes. I bulk loaded the database table from a csv file with the datetime fields in YYYYMMDD format and the load went OK; the db table shows 1994-12-31 12:00:00 AM in the datetime fields. They are type datetime2(7), NOT NULL in the db.

Comment: What are the details of the invalid cast exception? Can you edit your question to include them?

Comment: InvalidCastException was unhandled by user code. An exception of type 'System.InvalidCastException' in EntityFramework core dll but was not handled in user code.  Additional information: specific cast is not valid. Troubleshooting tips: Make sure the source type is convertible to the destination type.  When casting from a number the value must be a number less than infinity.